# Bootstrap DateTimePicker and jQuery problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm trying to use Bootstrap DateTimePicker on a Bootstrap-based HTML template. The problem is that there's a JS file called *foundation.js* which is included in the template and that file is killing DateTimePicker. When I don't include this file, DateTimePicker works, but lots of other functions of template (like tabs, image gallery etc.) stop working. When this file is included, DateTimePicker doesn't work. That foundation.js file is too big so I put it here: http://pastebin.com/fQhtpV2P

What I noticed is that there is obviously a whole jQuery v1.8.1 code included in that file. So I guess that this is the reason why DateTimePicker doesn't work since I'm including jQuery v2.1.1 library so these two are in conflict. I tried:

1. Remove the jQuery v1.8.1 code from foundation.js -> the same effect like removing the whole file; the picker works but all other functions from template doesn't work
2. Remove jQuery v2.1.1 library include -> DateTimePicker doesn't work
3. Remove the jQuery v1.8.1 code from foundation.js and replace it with jQuery v2.1.1 code -> nothing works

I also tried all combinations of including order, but no success. So, I can't remove that foundation.js and the picker won't work while that file is there. What should I do?

PS. my code is in Codeigniter so it's pretty complicated (in lots of files) but I can give you parts of the code if needed.

Comment: Where that foundation.js come from? Where did you take that template?

Comment: It's a part of that template. This is the template: http://www.wowthemes.net/studio-francesca-free-responsive-template/

Answer (score 1):

Try to use an older version of your picker, u can take a look at this link

http://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/

The picker simply doesn't show with jQuery 1.8 or give u an error??

Regards

Comment: Good idea, or else, you can try to load separately latest version of every library included in foundation.js

Comment: There's an error in console: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function

Comment: Have you included datetimepicker after foundation.js?

Comment: I ve seen someone use this $.noConflict() before the document ready and including 2 different version of jquery ( i haven't tested it ) .... u can give it a try or change your picker version

Comment: Oh, it works now! Seems that there was still a problem with including order. The problem was due to me putting the code and including datetimepicker.js at the header, while all other .js files (including foundation.js) were included in the footer, after the content. I already tried to move datetimepicker.js include after foundation.js but I obviously forgot to move the code which calls .datetimepicker() function under that as well. Thank you! PS. this thing with noConclifct() is interesting, I will take a look on it in case I will need newer jQuery for something other.

Answer (score 0):

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function
```

This kind of error is communly caused because you included the library that is depending on jquery before jquery itself.

Check your including order to be sure the dateTimePicker js file is included after JQuery